# what is the language encoding for .jade

Tags: pug

I want to write a .jade file on Notepad++ but I am not sure of language encoding option should I chose?

I have tried the following:

- HTML
- JavaScript

and yet there was no changes. the below is the piece of code I am writing:

```
doctype 5
html
  head
       title=title
             link(rel="styleSheet", href="bootstrap.min.css")

body
    div.container
        block contententer code here
```

Comment: Try to use doctype html.

Comment: no dear didint work @Duikboot

Comment: It's not clear what you want, please give more details, which language encoding do you mean? Do you want syntax highlighting? Do you set it via your editor (Notepad)? Or do you want to set the language attribute for your html document?